# Styling WinForm's controls

Tags: c#, winforms, styling

I've seen some softwares which just blew me away, that had incredible look. so I want to know how can I make controls more customizeable.

At the moment, I want to achieve a RichTextBox with a background, round edges and a diffrent select cursor. How can I do / learn how to do these kind of things?

Is it impossible without making my own control? if it is, I'd be happy to get some references to learn how to do so. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `OnPaint` event, develop your own controls etc. but it's cumbersome and using WinForms with this objective in mind is like eating soup with a fork. Try WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation). It allows you to customize UI, theme your application etc. very easily. WPF also seems to have a much brighter future ahead of itself than WinForms.

Comment: Does WPF restrict me in some way? can I do something in WinForms that I can't in WPF? The thing is, most programs I see are WinForms, why?! it has an amazing look!

Comment: Code-wise it's the same .NET stuff (there's some simplified data-binding in WPF etc. but that's not super important). The main difference is all about developing your apps visually, and WPF beats WinForms hands down in this aspect. It's WinForms restricting you, not the other way round.

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but if so.. why should I ever use WinForms?! and if I shouldn't why does people use it now? just the power of habit or there's something else?

Comment: People use it because it has been around for longer. WinForms is older. WPF came out with .NET 3.0.